# How add some permanent options to google search in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-search

Is it possible to permanently add some options to google search in Firefox. I'm tired of all these spam sites and I'd like to have my own list of banned words that should be always attached to the search (like `-torrent -xxx etc`).

Comment: You should probably have a look at this and create your own based on an example, since they apparently have created custom Google search engines and they work in Firefox: http://mycroftproject.com/google-search-plugins.html.

Comment: In Google Chrome you can even write your own custom query string like http://superuser.com/search?q=%s

Comment: @ShenalSilva: As you can in Firefox (introduced years before Chrome was even released).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have downloaded from the site Torben suggested google-3-months plugin as a template. It was installed in `..\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\???????.default\searchplugins\` directory.

I edited it following:

```
<SearchPlugin xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/" xmlns:os="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<os:ShortName>Google (despam)</os:ShortName>
<os:Description>Google</os:Description>
<os:InputEncoding>UTF-8</os:InputEncoding>
<os:Image width="16" height="16">data:image/x-icon;base64,... HERE COMES ENCODED ICON
</os:Image>
<SearchForm>http://www.google.com/search -torrent</SearchForm>
<os:Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="http://www.google.com/search?q={searchTerms} -torrent">
</os:Url>
</SearchPlugin>
```

After restart of firefox I had new search engine which did exactly what I wanted *i.e.* added `-torren` to search parameters.

Thanx Torben

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution.

**Find Firefox profil folder**

1. Menu > Help > Troubleshooting information (I don't have the english version)
2. Find a line with the folder profil

**Change file: search.json.mozlz4**

3. Make a backup of the file "*search.json.mozlz4*",
4. Install the addon in Firefox: [mozlz4-edit](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/mozlz4-edit/) (big red button should appear),
5. Then, open the file `search.json.mozlz4` with the AddOn,
6. Make changes:

   ```
   -"__searchForm": "https://www. google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q={searchTerms}",
   +"__searchForm": "https://www. google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q={searchTerms}+-inurl%3Aamazon.fr",
   ```

   then

   ```
   -"template": "https://www. google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q={searchTerms}",
   +"template": "https://www. google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q={searchTerms}+-inurl%3Aamazon.fr",
   ```

   then

   ```
   {
     "name": "q",
   -  "value": "{searchTerms}"
   +  "value": "{searchTerms}+-inurl%3Aamazon.fr"
   }
   ```

   Adapt as you like !
7. Save it
8. Close and open Firefox
9. Enjoy !

Probably repeat this operation after Firefox update.

Answer (score -1):

1. Extract the URL of the search page, replacing the search string with `%s`.
   For your example: `https://www.google.co.uk/search?&q=%s%20-torrent%20-xxx`
2. Create a new bookmark. Set the URL to the one you got in step 1.
3. Assign a keyword. For example, `torrent`. Press OK.
   [image]
4. Now you can search by typing in `torrent` followed by your search terms in the address bar.